# Move a tab to an existing Tab Group in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Is there any context menu action available to move a Tab to an existing `Tab Group`?  I do not want to create a `New [Tab] Group` or move to another window.

[image]

This is an operation I frequently want to do. [Less convenient] workarounds *do* exist:

- Shuffle around the chrome windows and then drag and drop the tab into the section maintained for that other `Tab Group`
- Organize all Tab Groups in their own separate windows. Then use the `Move Tab to Another Window` option and then drag the tab into the group

So the workarounds are a bit clunky.

I am on `macOS Monterey 12.5`

Comment: What OS is this for?  In Chrome on Windows 10 with several existing tab groups I have a context sub menu "Add Tab to Group" that lists all the existing groups, regardless of which window they're in.

Comment: @squillman  `macOS`: Updated the Q